# Running an application once after reboot

Tags: c#, registry, sccm, runonce

I'm currently working on a small application that removes a piece of software and re installs it. Part of the removal process requires a reboot, so I have had to relaunch the application on startup. I'm currently using a runonce registry key under local machine.

During testing, I've found that on some devices in our fleet, the exe starts before explorer, which is very bad for UX as the installation process takes ~20 minutes and leaves the user with a black screen for this time.

Initially, I used the runonce key under current user, however I ran into issues during deployment via SCCM.(I know there are ways to remove and reinstall using SCCM, but the requirements I was given state it needs to be an application)

So how can I run my exe once at startup, without getting a black screen?

Thanks!

Comment: dont make it a console app?

Answer (score 1):

How about dropping a shortcut to your installer into the startup folder and removing it once done with the install?

All users:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Current user:
C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Answer (score 0):

You could use the task scheduler to launch the application after boot/log-in with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Create two deployments one to uninstall software and other for re-install
Set the uninstall deployment as a dependency to re-install deployment and set configuration manager restart required to uninstall deployment.